# Search and retrieve from multiple Collection in MarkLogic?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

How can I fix the following code, if I would like to
specify multiple collections? (like 'pdf' AND 'systemA')

```
for $doc in fn:collection("pdf")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to get documents that are in **either** the `"A"` or `"B"` collections. in MarkLogic you can pass multiple URIs: `fn:collection(("A","B"))`. If you want documents that are in **both** the `"A"` and `"B"` collections simultaneously, you'll either have to do this as a search

```
cts:search(doc(), 
  cts:and-query((cts:collection-query("A"),cts:collection-query("B")),"unfiltered")
```

or do the set intersection manually

```
let $as := fn:collection("A")
return fn:collection("B")[not(. is $as)]
```

The search would be more efficient, since it can use indexes to resolve.